# Elasticsearch wildcard query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

can you help me understand, why simple query not working.
I have a simple index with default settings:

```
PUT my_index/doc/1
{
  "path": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"
}
```

Why the following query doesn't return anything?

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "_source": "path", 
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(path: *\\system32\\*.exe)"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the field in your query like this.

```
GET sample-index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "fields" : ["path.keyword"],
            "query" : """*\\system32\\*.exe"""
        }
    }
}
```

Output I got was :

```
    {   "took": 13,
        "timed_out": false,
        "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0   },   
        "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_index": "sample-index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
              "path": """C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"""
            }
          }
        ]
   }
 }
```

Here I have used **path.keyword** as when you post a new field (like you did in your question) without mapping, it will by default create a keyword field for it.
[check here for more](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html)

Extra tip: You can also apply regex over the field section if you want to check for multiple fields (i.e. : path,path1,pathcc etc.)

```
GET sample-index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "fields" : ["path*"],
            "query" : """*\\system32\\*.exe"""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for example.  What the reason for triple quotes? If I remove them, the result will be empty?

Comment: Did you try looking for the entry you posted using post command in your question?

`GET sample-index/_search/`

when I used the search query to see the entry I got this output

`{
        "_index": "sample-index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "path": """C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"""
        }
      }`